# SwiftUI: Using Toggles in Table, cannot pass a Binding to the Toggle

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to create a Table in SwiftUI. This Table will have three columns:

| Enabled | Name | Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Toggle that is on or off depending on the value of an item's *isEnabled* bool | The name of the item according to an item's *name* string | The version of the item according to the item's *version* string |

The data model I'm using looks like this:

```
let mods: [Mod] = [
    Mod(name: "Some cool mod", version: "1.2", isEnabled: true),
    Mod(name: "Another interesting item", version: "1.4", isEnabled: true),
    Mod(name: "Very Cool", version: "10.1.45", isEnabled: false)
]
```

I'm passing this data to another view (called *InstanceSettingMods*) using Binding. The Binding is defined in this child view like this:

```
@Binding var mods: [Mod]?
```

And in the parent view, it's being passed in like this:

```
InstanceSettingMods(mods: $mods)
```

I've had no problems creating and populating the table with the *Name* and *Version*, but I cannot figure out how to implement the *Enabled* column. The Toggle expects a Binding, but I don't know how to pass a Binding to it.

The Table is defined like this:

```
struct InstanceSettingMods: View {
    
    @Binding var mods: [Mod]?
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(mods!) {
            TableColumn("Enabled") { 
               TOGGLE GOES HERE
            }
            TableColumn("Name", value: \.name)
            TableColumn("Version", value: \.version)
        }
    }
}
```

I can pass the values of *isEnabled* into the Table and display them if I convert them to String like this:

```
struct InstanceSettingMods: View {

    @Binding var mods: [Mod]?
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(mods!) {
            TableColumn("Enabled") { toggleValue in
                Text(toggleValue.isEnabled.description)
            }
            TableColumn("Name", value: \.name)
            TableColumn("Version", value: \.version)
        }
    }

}
```

[Table with isEnabled values as Strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUS7b.png)

As Toggle expects a Binding, if I try to create the Toggle in this way, I get the error ***Cannot find '$toggleValue' in scope***:

```
TableColumn("Enabled") { toggleValue in
    Toggle("", isOn: $toggleValue.isEnabled)
}
```

If I remove the **$** from the definition, I get this error instead: ***Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'***

I would like to know how to create a toggle that would let me enable/disable each mod in the table.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to create a custom binding in this way:

```
Toggle("", isOn: Binding<Bool>(
   get: {
      return mod.isEnabled
   },
   set: {
      if let index = mods.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == mod.id }) {
         mods[index].isEnabled = $0
      }
   }
))
```